# To prove $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n $ is non empty

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

To prove $$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n $$ is non empty
where $A_n , n \in \mathbb{N}$ are non empty and finite sets and $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 ...$

Let this intersection be empty

Let $a \in A_1$. So $\exists k \in N , k >1$ such that $x \notin A_k $ and so $a \notin \cap_{n=k}^{\infty} A_n $.

Also $x \in A_{k-1}$ and so $x \in A_k$ which is a contradiction to fact that $x \notin A_k $

How do i proceed ? Any Hints ?

Comment: What are you talking about?! What are the sets $\;A_n\;$ , anyway? The claim is blatantly false if no conditions are put unto those sets

Comment: The question makes no sense. You need some conditions on $A_n$ for this to be true. Clearly $\{1\} \cap \{2\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Without telling us what $A_n$ is, your question is incomplete.

Comment: yeah i have edited. you people are all eager to downvote so fast. everyone makes mistake

Comment: @FrejaJessen We are also quick to upvote. My vote on a question is based on what I see at a given moment. If a question is missing vital details, that's a reason to downvote it. If it is not, I remove the downvote, as I just did.

Comment: @FrejaJessen Your question was very poorly written and senseless, and it took you a while to address comments and, finally, correct your question. Of course people will downvote such a sloppy question

Answer (score 1):

The finiteness of the sets is crucial, since otherwise we could, for example, let $A_n=(0,1/n)$, for which $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\cdots$ but $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\emptyset$.

Now if the intersection were empty, then each element $a\in A_1$ must be absent from some set $A_{n(a)}$ with $n(a)\gt1$. In that case, let $N=\sum_{a\in A_1}n(a)$, which is finite since $A_1$ is finite.  Then $A_N\subseteq A_{n(a)}$ since $N\ge n(a)$, so $a\not\in A_N$ for each $a$, hence $A_N=\emptyset$. But that contradicts the assumption that the individual sets are all non-empty, hence the intersection must be non-empty.

Comment: The sets are finite.

Comment: @5xum, I missed that part of the problem at first, and deleted my answer as soon as I saw it (but apparently not before your comment). I've edited to give an actual answer now.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $a \in A_1$. So $\exists k \in N , k >1$ such that $x \notin A_k $

This is false. For example, you could have $A_1=A_2=A_3=\cdots$ which shows that what you wrote is not true.

---

To actually solve your problem, you need to prove that the intersection is **not** empty, i.e. that there exists some element in the intersection.

To do that, here are some guidelines:

1. Think about the series of numbers $|A_1|, |A_2|, |A_3|,\dots$
2. Prove that the series above is a non-increasing sequence of positive integers.
3. From $2$, conclude that the series must be constant from some point on,
4. From that, conclude that from some point on, all $A_k$ are the same set.

Comment: 1.. Since number of elements in A is limited and we are removing those limited elements infinite times, so there must be some stage where only one element remains in the set and it will remain in continuing sets. I am thinking about other points, but is this correct?

Comment: @FrejaJessen That is not correct. For example, what if $A_1=A_2=A_3=\dots = \{1,2\}$? Then it is **not** true that only one element remains. **please** read all four points I wrote, and try to prove them one at a time. For example, ignore points $3$ and $4$ for a moment and simply answer this: can you prove my *second* point? Then, from $2$, can you prove my *third* point?

Comment: 2. that sequence is non inceasing as the sets are getting smaller or remains the same size. How to prove this ?

Comment: @FrejaJessen You prove the fact that a sequence is non-decreasing by taking a look at the definition of "non-decreasing", then proving that your sequence fits that definition.

Comment: How do prove point 2 ?

Comment: This sequence is non increasing as next set is subset of previous.

Comment: I already told you in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry but i am on first chapter of book and i donot know about sequences yet